# C Programming: Recursion

Tags: c, gcc, recursion, lvalue

so I wrote this simple recursion program and am getting an error when I compile it with GCC

> error: lvalue required as left
>   operand of assignment

Hopefully this isnt anything to serious, any insight is appreciated

THanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int factorial (int);

int main (void)


{

        int i = 0;
        int a = 0;

        printf("Please enter an integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &i);

        a = factorial (i);

        printf("\n\n%d factorial equals: %d \n", i, a);

        return 0;
}

int   factorial ( int  n )
        {
        if ( n  <= 0 )
                return 0 ;
        else
                f(n) = f( n-1) + 2;              
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

The following statement is not valid C:

```
            f(n) = f( n-1) + 2;
```

(I assume this is the line on which you got the error; you didn't say.)

You might want to try the following:

```
            return factorial(n-1) + 2;
```

but then the name `factorial` is misleading because that is *not* the correct formula for the [factorial function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Factorial.html).

Answer (score 3):

Why are you writing this

```
   f(n) = f( n-1) + 2;
```

I can't see any function named `f()`.
This is not the correct formula for calculation factorial of any number. Look at Greg's provided link.

Change it to

```
int  factorial (int  n)
    {
     if (n==1||n==0)
            return 1;
    else
            return n*factorial(n-1);              
    }
```

Comment: Would be best to describe to describe that you cannot assign a return value a value; mainly lvalue cannot be a function execution.

Comment: gives the solution, but if(n <= 1) might be better to prevent a fatal error if n is negative.

Answer (score 0):

The error is with f(n) = f(n+1) in your factorial function. Anything with parenthesis is a function in c and a function cannot be assigned a value. You probably want n = factorial(n+1);

Comment: It would compile but that wouldn't give the factorial... in fact it would be a recursive call which would be 'infinite' (until memory runs out).

Answer (score 0):

replace  f(n) = f( n-1) + 2;   with

```
return n*factorial(n-1)
```

and yes, 0! is one so add

```
if(n==0) return 1;
```

Comment: a is not defined in the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator = needs a *variable* on the left hand side, to which the value on the right hand side is assigned to. You can't assign something to a function, which is what f(n) is according to C syntax. This is assigning a value to lines of code, which makes no sense. The only thing that makes sense on the left hand side of a function is *something that can store a value*.

Functions can go on the right hand side of the assignment though, as long as they return something (they are not type void).

To get the factorial right you need to think through it a little more... first of all remember that you want the last value to be 1, not zero. And all of the numbers in the factorial are multiplied.